# Jquery SHOW other input when textbox is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i Show an input **#f_past_data** when the text **#f_past_farmaco** gets filled in?

**#f_past_farmaco** is a text input.

I tried this but doesn't work.

```
$('label[for=f_past_data], input#f_past_data').hide(); // hiding label

$("select#f_past_farmaco").change(function(){
    $(this).find("value").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")!==""){
            $('label[for=f_past_data], input#f_past_data').fadeIn();
            $('#f_past_data').css('display','block');

        }
        else{
            $('label[for=f_past_data], input#f_past_data').fadeOut();
            $('#f_past_data').css('display','none');
        }
    });
}).change();
```

HTML

```
<label for="f_past_farmaco">Farmaco </label>        
<input type="text" id="f_past_farmaco" name="f_past_farmaco" value="" class="form-control">
 <label for="f_past_data">Data </label>
 <input type="date" id="f_past_data" name="f_past_data" value="2017-02-19" class="form-control">
```

Comment: f_past_farmaco is a select input ?

Comment: Check if this works `$(document).on('keyup click keydown','#f_past_farmaco',function(){`

Comment: Could you please show enough of your HTML (think "*[mcve]*") that we can reproduce your situation, which allows us to provide you with specific help and other visitors, in future, with clear, precise help with a specific example upon which to base their own solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`change` event only applied to select fields and checkboxes, you need to use `keyup`,`keydown`,`keypress`, try this

```js
$(document).on('keyup',"#field1",function(){
     var val = $(this).val();
     if(val.length == 0)
     {
          $("#field2").hide();
     }
     else
     {
          $("#field2").show();
     }
})
```

```css
#field2{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <input type="text" id="field1"/>
    <input type="text" id="field2"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pre: Please remove any duplicate ID from your document and then try this code...

```
    $(document).on('keyup click keypress keydown','#f_past_farmaco',function(){
        $(this).find("value").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")!==""){
                $('label[for=f_past_data], #f_past_data').fadeIn();
                $('#f_past_data').css('display','block');

            }else{
                $('label[for=f_past_data], #f_past_data').fadeOut();
                $('#f_past_data').css('display','none');
            }
        });
    });
```